# Display/hide links cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp, hyperlink

Sorry im new to cakephp 3.0. In my user table, there are two user types, admin and public. How do I display/hide links according to user types in default.ctp? Can anyone guide me thanks!!

This is my app controller

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class AppController extends Controller
{
//...

public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('Flash');
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'index'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Pages',
            'action' => 'display',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);

   }
  public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
   $this->Auth->allow(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'add', 'index',                                             

   ]);
    }

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The AppController you've posted has nothing to do with what I understand of your request so that's got me a little confused. Either way, you can access the session of the current logged in user through session variables.

For example - if your users table had the column 'type' in which the values 'public' or 'admin' were stored, it would look something like this:

```
<?php if ($this->session->read('Auth.User.type') == 'admin') { ?>

    <a href="#">Link to admin functions</a>

<?php } else { ?>

    <a href="#">Boring public link</a>

<?php } ?>
```

That's assuming you're working with logged in users. If you haven't got that far yet, read the [CakePHP 3 tutorial on authentication and authorization](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html).